# Show that the intersection of the distinct subgroups of a $p$-group of index $p$ is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups

I've been struggling with this exercise (Exercise 8.2.28, *Introduction to Abstract Algebra* by Nicholson) for a few hours, and I haven't made much progress.

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ and let $H_1, \dots ,H_m$ be the distinct subgroups of $G$ of index $p$. If $N = H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_m$, show that $N \triangleleft G$ and that $x^p = 1$ for every coset $x$ in $G/N$.

From an earlier exercise, either $H_i \triangleleft G$ or $H_i = N(H_i)$ where $N(H_i)$ is the normalizer of $H_i$ for each $i$.

Furthermore, by Lagrange's Theorem, these subgroups are the ones of order $p^{n-1}$.

> Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of order $p^n$. Then there exists a series
> $$
> G = G_0 \supset G_1 \supset \cdots \supset G_n = \{ 1 \}
> $$
> of subgroups of $G$ such that $G_i \triangleleft G$, $|G_i| = p^{n-i}$, and $|G_i / G_{i+1}| = p$ for all $i$.

I have a strong feeling that this is somehow related but I've been stuck for hours on how to use it. I have no idea where to go from here and I've made so little progress. Can someone provide me a hint rather than a full answer? I still want to be challenged.

Comment: In fact, proper subgroups of finite $p$-groups are never equal to their own normalizers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin to wit, normalizers "grow" in nilpotent groups.  Would that be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $N$ is normal, note that if $H$ is of index $p$, then the index of $H$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, so $H$ is normal. Thus, $N$ is the intersection of normal subgroups, hence is normal.

Alternatively, if $H$ has index $p$ and $x\in G$, then $xHx^{-1}$ also has index $p$. Therefore,
$$xNx^{-1} = x\left(\bigcap_{[G:H]=p}H\right)x^{-1} = \bigcap_{[G:H]=p}xHx^{-1} = N.$$

To prove the coset of $x$ has exponent $n$, note that for every $H$ of index $p$, $G/H$ has order $p$, so $(xH)^p=eH$; therefore, $x^p\in H$.

Thus, $x^p$ lies in every subgroup of index $p$, hence in their intersection,